# Android AVD on Eclipse shows 'Blank Screen' with no activity

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I start my AVD emulator, the emulator just shows blank screen with 'android' written at the center. I waited for half an hour but nothing changed.

I am using Android SDK 2.1 and Eclipse 3.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317167/helloandroid-emulator-problem/7167568#7167568

Answer (score 4):

I see that quite a lot. In my case, I can clear it by shutting the emulator window, doing 'adb kill-server' followed by 'adb start-server', then restarting the emulator. I have also had more success launching the emulator first before letting the debugger launch it when I start debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with a blank black screen after the emulator was started by Titanium and none of the emulator buttons such as Menu or Home did anything.

To fix it I entered the following commands from the sdk / tools directory:

```
android list avd
```

This listed the emulator images.  In my case it listed two:

```
Available Android Virtual Devices:
    Name: titanium_3_WVGA854
    Path: C:\Users\xxx\.android\avd\titanium_3_WVGA854.avd
  Target: Android 1.6 (API level 4)
    Skin: WVGA854
  Sdcard: C:\Users\xxx\.titanium\android.sdcard
---------
    Name: titanium_8_WVGA854
    Path: C:\Users\xxx\.android\avd\titanium_8_WVGA854.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
          Based on Android 2.2 (API level 8)
    Skin: WVGA854
  Sdcard: C:\Users\xxx\.titanium\android.sdcard
```

In my case I wanted the Android 2.2 API so I entered

```
emulator @titanium_8_wvga854
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I also see a black screen only (w/o logo) when starting the AVD provided by open-nfc.