# Emulator hangs at boot animation Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using SDK on Windows Vista. Everytime I start the emulator it just hangs at the android animation. On log cat it displays Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

After this nothing happens. I have gone through all related posts on this forum but nothing works for me. I have even reinstalled everything twice but nothing works.

Can anyone please help? I have tried on target 2.1, 2.3 and 3.0

Comment: How long are you waiting? On my machine, it takes about 10 minutes for the emulator to start.

Comment: definitely wait at least 10 minutes on windows and maybe more on Vista. There are two android animations on startup. The first one which looks typewriter like and the second chrome splash. If you're at the chrome splash, let it keep going, it's loading libraries and eventually your apk... When you do get it up and running don't close it, you can reload the emulator with your new source changes as long as you don't change major programming structure

Comment: I had this same issue.  Here's how I fixed it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317167/helloandroid-emulator-problem/7167568#7167568

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/running-the-new-intel-emulator-for-android/10772162#10772162It helped me. Emulator starts in just a few secs. Also, try using a memory optimizer to open up the Free portion (not the Available portion) of your system memory if you get error code 8 / memory issues.

Answer (score 8):

I had similar problem. All I did was delete the emulator and created another emulator targeted at the appropriate API Level.

Yeah! Somehow it worked for me this way....

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact same issue on windows 7 64 bit and tried many of the solutions that I found on this site including deleting my AVD and recreating it but nothing seemed to work.  In the end, I resolved this by editing the AVD and setting the "Max VM application heap" from the default of 24 to 32.  This instantly resolved my problem on windows 7. The android screen that previously appeared to hang now launches up in under 1 minute.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: The AVDs took forever to start (more than 10 minutes). I deleted them and created new ones, and now they start in a few seconds, as always.

Answer (score 2):

click on the button "Opens android device manager" on the menu icons, delete all the virtual devices, create new ones (without the snapshot checked).

try again

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue. I tried uninstalling & reinstalling several times. I'm guessing that you're using Eclipse and starting the emulator from within the IDE. My solution was to try it from the command line; type android (assuming that the PATH is set correctly), choose an AVD, start it & wait.  Another suggestion would be to create a smaller AVD (smaller screen). this will have a great impact on the emulator performance.

Comment: modify your emulator config file( path: .android/avd/your_avd_name.avd/config.ini)

change to  hw.gpu.enabled=no  for disabling host gpu

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue using Windows 7 64-bit.  Here's how I fixed it:

[HelloAndroid emulator problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317167/helloandroid-emulator-problem/7167568#7167568)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this problem with an SDK Version higher than 22.3, see my answer in the post referred to above by walkerk:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22800240/2326613

You will get "floating point exception" in Intel API 19, and the behavior described by the OP in this post for Intel versions prior.   The ARM APIs should still work (slowly).

In the earlier APIs, "adb shell logcat" command (run in shell) on the "stuck" emulator will show a loop around an error involving " SSLCertificateSocketFactory " failing.

Answer (score 0):

after long time try and error and a lot of time waist in different fourm , this problem ( Black page on SDK boot or maintain in boot animation,  easily solved by  selecting different skin in emulator ( insted of first chois that was dynamic skin  , ) I select last skin "wxga " . emulator boot in less than 1 min

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem **only** with `API Level 15`

Solution worked for me:

from `SDK Manager` i remove and reinstall System Images related to `API-15`

and next i create new `Virtul Device`