# Problems running the Android emulator on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

So I want to get into making Apps for Android. I read and followed [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) to set up everything I need, but when running my first little App, I get the following messages:

```
[2012-05-28 16:09:54 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2012-05-28 16:09:54 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2012-05-28 16:09:54 - HelloAndroid] Performing jannis.test.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2012-05-28 16:09:54 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MyAVD'
[2012-05-28 16:09:54 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MyAVD'
[2012-05-28 16:10:55 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2012-05-28 16:10:55 - Emulator] emulator: Failed to open the HAX device!
[2012-05-28 16:10:55 - Emulator] HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
[2012-05-28 16:10:55 - Emulator] 
[2012-05-28 16:10:55 - Emulator] emulator: Open HAX device failed
[2012-05-28 16:10:55 - Emulator] 
[2012-05-28 16:10:55 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 1455
[2012-05-28 16:10:55 - Emulator] 
[2012-05-28 16:10:55 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2012-05-28 16:10:55 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Besides the fact that I have no idea what it means, of course I did some searching, and someone here had about the same problem: [Running the new Intel emulator for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/android-running-the-new-intel-emulator)

There it is suggested one install the *Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager* using the SDK Manager. I try it and then, again, get an error:

```
Preparing to install archives
Unexpected Error installing 'Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager, revision 1':
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
```

I have no idea what to do. Can anyone help me out here, please?

Regards

Comment: Can you try solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/android-running-the-new-intel-emulator

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the HAX stuff, try reducing the memory you give to the device to 800MB for example. Looks like it is requesting a bit too much.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this page: [Configuring Virtual Machine Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Sadly, my processor does not support virtualization. Is there anything else I can do? (http://products.amd.com/pages/NotebookCPUDetail.aspx?id=18&f1=&f2=&f3=&f4=&f5=&f6=&f7=&f8=&f9=)

Comment: Not a thing that I know. Sorry and good luck with your app.

Comment: Without virtualization you can't run the Intel hardware accelerated images, you can still run the basic slow ones though. Are you sure your CPU does not support it, perhaps it is just turned off in the bios, it usually is by default.