# Android Studio and VT-x

Tags: android, virtualization, genymotion

I have a problem with virtualization technology. I bought new laptop Y50-70 that support this fetaure but I cannot start my android emulator. I get error that my processor doesn't support VT-x. When I enable virtualization in BIOS it is disabled in win 8.1 and if I disable it in BIOS it is enabled in win 8.1 but it still doesn't work. I installed all plugins but it didn't help. Please help !

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13748687/295004

Comment: Try genymotion emulators https://www.genymotion.com but you better use some real device.

Comment: I have already use genymotion because standard emulator in android studio never works. Morrison Chang information from this topic doesn't help me.

Comment: I have solved that problem. At some computers (if you use visual studio and android studio) you have to enable VT-x in BIOS and disable Hyper-V in your system ( when you are using android studio ). If you want to work in VS ( windows phone emulator ) you have to enable Hyper-V ( and I think that you have to disable virtualization but I didn't check that idea ) Sorry for my english xD