# Android emulator fails to start after closing

Tags: android, android-emulator

Using Eclipse (4.2.1) with Android SDK and Virtual Device Manager installed, I'm able to successfully launch the emulator with a device image, run code, etc, etc - however, if I close the emulator any subsequent attempts to restart it fail with the following error:

```
emulator: Failed to open the hax module
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
```

If I recreate the virtual device and overwrite the existing definition, it will start again (but just the one time). Running OSX 10.8.2, and the AVD is 4.2, Level 17.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Try going to system processes and shutting down the `adb.exe` process.

Comment: Did you see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/android-running-the-new-intel-emulator) might or might not be related.

Comment: @Cygwinnian - thanks, tried that with no luck.

Comment: @wtsang02 - took a look at that post, thanks. seems like it's specific to running the AVD in x86 CPU mode, which I was. I tried switching to ARM but am getting similar behavior (though with less descriptive error message)

Comment: @ChrisPiazza I hate when these problems happen with emulators.

Answer (score 1):

Feh... figured it out. I have multiple screens and the issue only happens after I move the emulator to one of the secondary monitors. In that case, a negative position value is getting written to emulator-user.ini. Deleting the file fixes the problem (or just leaving the emulator on the main laptop screen).

Found it in [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40038) on code.google.com