# Improving response time on android

Tags: android

I am using android emulator to test my project. Are there any specific settings that can give a better response time on the device? Because it is taking a long time to even enter username and password on my login page and click submit. Help Needed.

Comment: Real device or High configured PC can help you only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use x86 emulator - it is a lot faster than ARM emulator.

Comment: is it something to do with the RAM size also? or only the processor change would suffice?

Comment: i am getting the following log when i changed the device from ARM to x86 emulator..
emulator: Failed to open the HAX device!
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: Open HAX device failed
creating window 0 0 534 854
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Comment: Look at this answer on how to install HAX, you need to do it before you can have HW accelerated emulator - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10772162/72746