# android emulator in ADT plugin not running

Tags: android, eclipse, audio, android-emulator

I'm using **Eclipse ADT** plugin for **android** development. I came across some problems and I remove all my existing **emulators** and create a new one. when I run an android project and  start the **emulator**, it just pop up and freezes with a black screen even before it start **Android** os.

[image]

and the **progress tab** shows,`No operations to display at this time.` and the **logcat** displaying `I/ServiceManager(270): Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...` over and over again. And the **console** shows

```
[2013-12-02 14:54:03 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
[2013-12-02 14:54:03 - Emulator] 
[2013-12-02 14:54:04 - AndroidV4Virtusel] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-12-02 14:54:04 - AndroidV4Virtusel] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

But the **emulator** never launched. No rusalt although I restart the IDE.

when I restart the **adb** using **DDMS** perspective it gives following error.

```
[2013-12-02 15:22:50 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2013-12-02 15:22:51 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
```

The **avd manager** also shows the **emulator** as a valid **emulator**[image]

And when I close the **emulator** the **console** shows,

```
[2013-12-02 15:34:23 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device emulator-5554
[2013-12-02 15:34:23 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device emulator-5554
[2013-12-02 15:34:23 - ViewServerDevice]Unable to debug device: My1 [emulator-5554]
[2013-12-02 15:34:23 - hierarchyviewer]Missing forwarded port for emulator-5554
[2013-12-02 15:34:23 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get the focused window from device emulator-5554
```

So can someone help me? Thank you!!!

Comment: Do you have any ui in your application?

Comment: Yep. It has a Ui. But the thing is the emulator not starting. It freezes even before it launch android os. No matter how long I waited, it just shows the black screen.

Comment: Could it be something wrong with my IDE???

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To solve this, go to Window --> Open Perspective --> DDMS. 
In the DDMS View, look for devices on the left of your screen. You should see a bar having about 12 icons. Click on the down arrow and click the "reset ADB". It should work afterwards.

Comment: I did. But rusalt was the same.

Comment: Can you see the emulator under "Devices" ?

Comment: yes, it shows in the DDMS. also it displays the emulator as online.

Comment: Ok try this. Create a new avd. Then go to Run --> Run configurations --> Target --> Select "Always prompt to pick device" and then run the application. Choose the newly created avd.

Comment: new one also not working. Console shows `HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode`

Comment: Check this answer to install the HAX module. Let me know if it works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/running-the-new-intel-emulator-for-android

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I was able to run an **emulator** with **Android 2.2**. But unable to run an emulator in **Android 4.2** which is my applications **target**. So i just removed Android **4.2 (API 17)** and just reinstall it. Later on emulator starts fine. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the blue stacks as your emulator.. its really faster and efficient.. If you are using the Blue Stacks, first start your blue stacks and then eclipse or whatever the IDE you are using...

you can also have a look here

http://infopulseukraine.com/eng/blog/Software-Development/Mobile/Bluestacks_Eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to Jimi's answer, the easiest way to restart adb is to type the following command into a console window:

```
adb kill-server
```

If you get an error about adb command not found, then you can either add the android system tools path to your PATH key in environment variables, or just navigate to the tools directory and execute the command from there:

```
./AndroidSdk/platform-tools
```

After killing the server, make sure it's restarted correctly by typing:

```
adb devices
```

Which should show you a list of connected devices.

After restarting adb, the device manager should automatically refresh, otherwise try restarting device manager or selecting the refresh window button.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is something wrong with your AVD properties,change it to where it compatible to your android projects,that's all.