# Android Studio Emulator not working

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I downloaded Android Studio about 3 months ago and have not been able to get the emulator to work. I've checked out so many pages on Stackoverflow about the emulator and they say use `GenyMotion` (which caused another set of problems for me) and other things like lower the Emulator ram. I have tried all these things and not succeeded.

My emulator shows a black screen and incredibly small buttons which I know is not how it should look (I watched video's on youtube)

I would really appreciate some help, here are my PC's stats

> Ram:2GB Processor: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5800 @ 3.20GHz 3.20GHz 32
>   bit windows 7

If you can help me I'll be extremely grateful, I'm a student with not enough to buy an Android Device.

Comment: do you have the snapshot option enabled?

Comment: Can you post your AVD configuration and also a screenshot of how your emulator looks like?

Comment: Sam Dunk, I do have snapshot enabled.

Comment: G3M, I haven't got enough points to upload images, but the emulator looks like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325051/android-emulator-in-adt-plugin-not-running

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the need to test your application's performance exclusively on an `ARM processor` you can alternatively use other emulators like Genymotion which have a free version and uses your PC's processor instead of simulating an `ARM`: http://www.genymotion.com/