# Cannot emulate Android device in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-emulator

I have downloaded the [Eclipse with Android environment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=p) and have created an emulator with the following settings:

[image]

However, when I run the Android emulator (with all the combinations I am can), the Android device never gets past the following screen:

[image]

I have tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325051/android-emulator-in-adt-plugin-not-running) with no luck. After extensive Googling I cannot find a solution. Is it the case that, due to my hardware, I am unable to emulate? I have an AMD processor with a NVidia GPU.. but I cannot imagine everyone else with similar hardware is unable to emulate Android devices.

Comment: Your screenshot clearly says that you need to install `Google API ARM(armeabi-v7a)` system image for `Android 5.0(API21)` from `SDK Manager` otherwise your emulator would not be launched.

Answer (score 1):

the first picture actually told the reason,"this AVD may not work unless you install the Google APIs ARM(armeabi-v7a)system image for Android 5.0(API 21) first", have you installed the Google APIs ARM(armeabi-v7a)system image for Android 5.0(API 21)?

Comment: I have got it installed, see: http://i.imgur.com/xY5tkQc.png. I installed all the defaults that came with the Android / Eclipse bundle. I have no idea why that message is there.