# Failed to open HAX device (Android)

Tags: android, windows, haxm

I get the typical HAX error. Win7 x64, i7-2630QM

```
emulator: Failed to open the HAX device!
emulator: Open HAX device failed
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
```

The drivers are installed, virtualization is enabled in the BIOS, yet HAX still refuses to work. It used to work, but stopped after I reinstalled Windows. I believe, both Windows versions were the same, x64 Professional.

Comment: Have you tried this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/running-the-new-intel-emulator-for-android/10772162#10772162

Comment: Scrolled through all the answers, apparently Avast hates devs (loses it's shit every time I launch something I wrote in VS). Uninstalled Avast, reinstalled HAXM drivers, everything works now. Thanks.

Comment: Follow the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/running-the-new-intel-emulator-for-android) to the similar question which is already answered. Do read the **comments** of the first answer as well. Also, if you are having a problem that the screen of **AVD** is **persistently black**, then check the "**Use Host GPU**" checkbox while creating/editing your AVD.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like when you reinstalled Windows, your HAXM drivers got blown away.  Have you tried re installing them?  If not, you should probably get the latest versions:  http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

This question is pretty old - did you get it to work? I was wondering if the comment above helped?

Comment: As explained in my comment, the issue was Avast breaking virtualization for some reason. Resolved by switching to MSE.