# Failed to open the HAX device! HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

My Android emulator is running properly but it is showing this error every time I start the 
emulator.

> Starting emulator for AVD AVD_for_Nexus_4 emulator: Failed to open the
>   HAX device! HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
>   emulator: Open HAX device failed emulator: emulator window was out of
>   view and was recentered

I do not understand what is the exact problem.

Comment: Did you install HAX emulator using AVD? HAX is used to dedicate a portion of RAM to emulator for fast boot and app installation.

Comment: yeah.. i installed it. so why it is showing this message?

Comment: Did you just download it or installed it ? i.e. you assigned some RAM

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running the new Intel emulator for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/running-the-new-intel-emulator-for-android)

Comment: @RohanKandwal  What does assigning RAM have to do with HAX?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky While installing RAM HAX presents with an option to allocate RAM, assign very low RAM and there won't be any difference but when assigned enough, you will find your emulator more smooth and fast.

Comment: Follow the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/running-the-new-intel-emulator-for-android) to the similar question which is already answered. Do read the comments of the first answer as well. Also, if you are having a problem that the screen of **AVD** is **persistently black**, then check the "**Use Host GPU**" checkbox while creating/editing your AVD.

Answer (score 67):

I think you are trying to run an emulator based on x86. I got the same error when I just download the HAXM under Extras category of Android SDK Manager. Actually, you need install it.
Go to the directory of extras and run the installation of HAXM. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I dont have such thing

Comment: Michelle's solution works for me. On the SDK Manager go to: Extras > Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer). Then go to your SDK's folder / Extras / Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and install.

Comment: Mac users go to Applications, right click on Android Studio.app, reveal package contents, sdk/extras/intel/Hardw.../IntelHAXM....dmg

Answer (score 24):

The solution of Rohan will fix the problem as the error message will not be shown but the emulator will not use the hardware acceleration and thus be again very slow.

I recommend instead to install the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10772162/891479

Comment: That is a very outdated solution and approach.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem recently.

First you need to install HAXM in the Android SDK Manager (from the error message I think you already did that). This will enable the emulator to use the HAXM framework, and for this it needs to open the HAX device. On your system this cannot be found, hence the error message.

To make this device available, you need to install the HAXM driver from Intel. You can find it here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager (You also need to enable virtualization in your computer BIOS).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a note, virtualization is enabled on Mac by default. For others, this link should be helpful - https://manual.cs50.net/virtualization/

Answer (score 3):

If you found “HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode” problem while running android SDK. This mean your computer CPU must be intel core and must support “Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager”. It means that you have configured the emulator in a way which is not supported by your operating system.

See this link solving the problem http://www.javaexperience.com/hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode/#ixzz2p3inMj34

**Update : -**

The link is down at the moment so posting archieved link of the webpage -
https://web.archive.org/web/20151024002104/http://www.javaexperience.com/hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode/

If your CPU isn't intel, then you have to edit your AVD and choose "CPU/ABI" as "ARM". For more details, please visit the link above.

Comment: this link is broken

Answer (score 3):

I just had to uninstall HAXM and install it again. Then it started working again. Hope this helps someone!

Edit:

Oh wow, this was a long time ago. I have been using [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) for a few months now, and never had any issues like that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Just after enabling Internet Virtualization from BIOS. After that let the system boot and install HAXM once again. Now emulator will run faster than before and HAXM will work. Enjoy!!

Answer (score 1):

Check if the RAM configured in HAX installation is equal or lower than your AVD RAM ([How to fix: "HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031903/how-to-fix-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation-mode)) that fixed mine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and the other fixes didn't help me, but changing the CPU type the emulator used did get it working.

Create a new emulator and try using mips or arm for the cpu selection