# Why does my Emulator not work?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am using `Eclipse 4.4` and for some reason whenever I try to start an emulator I get the following errors:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'doridX'
emulator: Failed to open the HAX device!
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: Open HAX device failed
```

Does anyone know what causes this and how I can fix it? I have currently tried:

- Deleting the virtual device and recreating it.
- Closing Eclipse and restarting the programme.
- Closing all open emulators and try launching it again.
- Uninstalling all packages related that were installed on Eclipse and reinstalling them.

The settings for my AVD are:

- AVD name: droidX
- Device: Nexus 5 (4.95", 1080 x 1920: xxhdpi)
- Target: Android 4.4.2 - API Level 19
- CPU/ABI: Intel Atom (x86)
- Keyboard: Hardware keyboard present
- Skin: No skin
- Front Camera: None
- Back Camera: None
- Memory Options: RAM: 768   VM Heap: 64
- Internal Storage: 50 MiB
- SD Card: 50 MiB
- Emulation Options: None

Comment: HAX? Is that something similar to Intel HAXM?

Comment: @schneiti I'm not sure to be honest, I've just created an AVD with the options listed and tried to run it, I haven't come across HAXM before although I am aware as to what it is.

Comment: alright, I was just confused to read HAX without the M. This might be off-topic, but as soon as I installed the Android IDE, I installed HAXM as well. Without that accelleration, developement is impossible! I just got one more question: You wrote you are using `Eclipse 4.4`, so I guess this is standard Eclipse with Android plugins? Have you tried using Eclipse ADT version and whether the emulator is running there? Cause Eclipse is known to cause Trouble [see here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). That can be obtained from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

[Running the new Intel emulator for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/running-the-new-intel-emulator-for-android)

or

[Failed to open the HAX device! HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857256/failed-to-open-the-hax-device-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation)

And let us know which, if any, worked.