# Emulator error - Open HAX device failed

Tags: android, android-emulator

My Android emulator is not launching my App. Emulator launches perfectly but it doesn't launch app. I got following bunch of errors while launching the Emulator.

How can I solve these issues?

```
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: Failed to open the HAX device!
Failed to allocate memory: 1455
emulator: Open HAX device failed
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

My emulator settings:

- Device: 3.7 WVGA
- Target: Android 4.2.2 (API 17)
- CPU: Intel Atom(x86)
- RAM: 512
- VM heap: 32

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to open the HAX device! HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857256/failed-to-open-the-hax-device-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation)

Comment: I think you are trying to run an emulator based on x86. just download the HAXM under Extras category of Android SDK Manager.

Comment: I have download HAXM in Extras category. but from that time my Eclipse IDE is not working..:( and whenever i try to open it stuck on Android SDK content Loader (0%)

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of a missing driver for graphics card. Your warning suggests that it is a problem with OpenGL ES emulation. Make sure to click "Use Host GPU" option while creating the AVD. Also install the driver for your video card.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/172312/stuck-with-launching-new-emulator