# HAXM configuration in android studio

Tags: android, android-activity, haxm

I tried to run a simple Android chat app from GitHub. I think there's a problem with my HAXM configuration. When I run the app I see these errors:

```
HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode

emulator The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.

emulator: AVD RAM size = 1536 MB

emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 768 MB

emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.

emulator: warning: opening audio output failed creating window 61 83 462 820

emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857256/failed-to-open-the-hax-device-hax-is-not-working-and-emulator-runs-in-emulation

Comment: It appears that the RAM configured in HAXM installation is lower than your AVD RAM

Comment: Reinstall haxM with at least 2GB of space

Comment: it appears on the installer of the haxm limits for up to 1.9mb ,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

your HAXM RAM is lower than your AVD RAM.

Solutions:

1. Re-run you HAXM installation and increase RAM to match that of AVD(emulator).
2. Alternatively, decrease RAM of AVD(emulator) to match that of HAXM.

Answer (score 18):

Reinstall HAXM with more RAM:

```
sudo $ANDROID_SDK/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/silent_install.sh -u
sudo $ANDROID_SDK/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/silent_install.sh -m 1024
```

Answer (score 12):

The memory needed by this AVD should not be exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.

- It should be less than RAM set for HAMX.
- Go to `~\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager \intelhamx_android.exe`.
- Reinstall intel HAXM and set its RAM to 1024MB.
- Edit your AVD set its RAM to 768MB.
- Build and run your application.

If you cant change the RAM via reinstalling it means you installed HAXM via Android Studios.

1. **Ctrl + Alt + S**
2. click on **SDK Tools**
3. **uncheck** the box for **Intel HAXM** (Intel HAXM Installer)
4. **click Apply**
5. **recheck** the box for **Intel HAXM** and the program should now ask you to **reenter the RAM Usage** via slider or number

Answer (score 3):

Be sure when you increase your HAXM RAM configuration that your computer is able to handle this increased RAM. I use a 4GB RAM macbook pro that almost stopped responding after I increased HAXM RAM to 2GB. It may be a better option to decrease your AVD RAM.

Answer (score 1):

After re-installing HAXM with more (ideally more than 1536 MB) space solves the problem.

How to install HAXM for MAC - 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x

How to install HAXM for Windows  -
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Answer (score 1):

Just go to:-

Help >> Edit Custom VM options >> (see the picture below) >> Then close the file >> Restart android studio

[image]

Answer (score -3):

You have to increase the amount of RAM memory in:
Tools >> Android >> AVD manager

Select your AVD, press "Edit this AVD" and under Advanced settings set the amount of RAM to i.e. 1500Mb

That will do the trick

Comment: That increases memory used by the virtual device, not memory allocated to HAXM