# I am getting error when i install my Android app in device Redmi 3s prime, and it is working on genymotion emulator

Tags: android, installation, apk

I'm having this error:

> $ adb push
>   F:\skylixwork\CollagePhoto\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
>   /data/local/tmp/com.collagephoto java.io.IOException: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>   Error while
>   Installing APK

Installation failed with message `INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER`.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

Comment: restart your android studio Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: this is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Application Installation Failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718044/android-studio-application-installation-failed)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer for my question.

solution :-  (1)

enable developer mode - In your phone, go to Settings, About phone and click on MIUI version 7 times. You’ll see a pop up which says you are a developer now.

Go back to Settings, Additional settings, Developer options and enable USB Debugging.

Connect your phone to your PC/Mac and on the phone authorize your computer

go back to Developer options, scroll down to find Turn on MIUI optimization and disable it. Your phone will be rebooted

solution :-  (2)

enable developer mode - In your phone, go to Settings, About phone and click on MIUI version 7 times. You’ll see a pop up which says you are a developer now.

Go back to Settings, Additional settings, Developer options and enable USB Debugging.

Connect your phone to your PC/Mac and on the phone authorize your computer.

go back to Developer options, scroll down to find `Install via USB`: and just turn on it.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Works !

1. enable developer mode - In your phone, go to Settings, About phone and click on MIUI version 7 times. You’ll see a pop up which says you are a developer now.
2. Go back to Settings, Additional settings, Developer options and enable USB Debugging.
3. Connect your phone to your PC/Mac and on the phone authorize your computer
4. go back to Developer options, scroll down to find Turn on MIUI optimization and disable it. Your phone will be rebooted
5. I solved my issue this way.

Comment: Thanks! Turning off MIUI optimization is the key step!

Comment: Worked!! after disabling  MIUI optimization. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using **xiaomi redmi note 4x** and after Turning on **install via USB**, Turning off **MIUI optimization** is the main objective from developer option to run app via USB! This works for me

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to check  update of adb version. Aslo check the your [Run Apps on a Hardware Device](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#setting-up)

For more information refer this solution [ADB connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411295/error-adb-connection-erroran-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-r/12084091)

Try above solutions. hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

1 adb devices check your device is ok

2 reboot your devices

3 adb install -r  F:\skylixwork\CollagePhoto\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk

Comment: no its not working for me error:- adb install -r F:\skylixwork\CollagePhoto\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
[100%] /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER]