# Android Studio Error (Instant run related)

Tags: android, android-studio

I get this error message after I moved my project folder to another location on my pc and tried to run my app.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi7q2.png)

```
Installation failed with message Invalid File:
C:\Users\Zhong\AndroidStudioProjects\HappyBirthday\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

But actually my project folder is currently under `D:\\`

Everything works fine with instant run disabled, but if I enable instant run and click the run button, this error message will appear again.

It seems that the paths of those files are not automatically changed in some files.

I've tried to find some settings to fix that but no luck. I'm new to android developing, please help me with this simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn off Instant Run, you won't lose anything :)

But if you want, you can try to rebuild the project. Click Build > Clean project. Also you may go to a project folder, then in "app" folder, delete a folder "build" and then again rebuild a project in Android Studio.

Comment: Actually I've already tried that one (Clean Project). This particular error does go away, but after I successfully install the app on my phone, it won't run.Log:

Comment: 05-24 18:48:53.841 21967-21967/top.aluminumk.happybirthday E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: top.aluminumk.happybirthday, PID: 21967
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{top.aluminumk.happybirthday/top.aluminumk.happybirthday.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "top.aluminumk.happybirthday.MainActivity" on path:......

Comment: I can't understand, have you deleted the apk from a smartphone?

Comment: no. but once i disable instant run everything will go back to normal again.

Comment: But why don't you want to uninstall the apk? Instant Run saves some information there.

Comment: Maybe read something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718044/android-studio-application-installation-failed or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757663/i-getting-error-when-i-install-my-android-studio-project-in-device-redmi-3s-prim?

Comment: i attached a new smartphone to my computer and i still get something like java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{top.aluminumk.happybirthday/top.aluminumk.happybirthday.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "top.aluminum             again, if i disable instant run and re-run the app from android studio everything works fine

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest, please. Also maybe a MainActivity.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i think this problem has nothing to do with these files， for if i create a new project and paste these files to my new project folder, i can use instant run normally. but, if  i move the new project    folder to another location, this kind of error will appear again. so i suppose i just need to find a way to change my project folder path manually for instant run.