# Android Studio - Application installation failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3, android-instant-run

I've `instant run` enabled on `android studio 2.3` . When I want to run the app on my device this error appears:

> Installation failed with message . It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

[image]

After clicking ok I get this:

> Session 'app':Error Installing APKs

I've checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687607/application-installation-failed-in-android-studio) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718044/android-studio-application-installation-failed) but none of them are helping me indeed as I do need to enable `instant run`(otherwise it is taking a lot of time for the project I am working on).
My device: Asus Zenfone 2 Laser ZE500KL

Answer (score -1):

As per my knowledge about this issue there can be two reasons for that:

1. First is that your app is already installed with the same package name but with different certificate, To resolve this check if your phone has that app already installed then uninstall it and try to install new one.
2. The second reason can be that you are trying to install the application that has minimum SDK version higher than the Android version of device. To solve this make sure that the minimum SDK version defined in your project's "build.gradle" is lower than the Android version of your device.

Hope it will help!

Answer (score -3):

Try using `File>Invalidate Caches/Restart` and then select `Invalidate and Restart`..
This happens for me too sometimes and doing so helps me.