# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS when installing a newer version of apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

**UPDATE:** I believe this is not because of apk version conflicts, because I removed emulator and rebuilt new one and same error occurs.

I'm trying to install a newer version of an apk in Android Studio 3.1.3. And I see the error:

[image]

I tried to uninstall old apk in Emulator and then wipe device data in Emulator Manager, and then reboot Android Studio But not helping, I still could not install apk with the same error. Request help, thanks!

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: try to restart your emulator

Answer (score 1):

The APK you are trying to install does not contain the native libraries that work on your device's or emulator's CPU architecture.

Look inside the APK for the available directories under "lib/", that will indicate which ABIs are supported. E.g. `unzip -lv app.apk | grep "lib/"`

Then compare this with the architectures supported by your device: `adb shell getprop | grep abi`

Comment: This answer makes sense. ABIs supported in your app vs ABI of the emulator do not match. Check apps' ABI and create a new emulator with new ABI

Answer (score 0):

First, Disable Instant Run

**To disable Instant Run -**

Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run

```
                   OR
```

1. Clean your project
2. Rebuild the project.
3. Run your project without Instant run.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted apk project files and rebuilt one. but same error.

Comment: Did you follow the above steps?

Comment: I did, I suspect the apk does not work on certain Android versions.

Comment: Go through with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718044/android-studio-application-installation-failed