# Pixel launcher keeps stopping issue in Android 7.1.1 (API 25) emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-7.1-nougat

I have created an Emulator using android 7.1.1 (API 25) CPU X86. When I start the emulator its showing `pixel launcher keeps stopping` issue. I have checked with CPU x86_64 also but same issue.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here is my details config:

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution, yet?

Answer (score 15):

Selecting emulated performance --> graphics:Software-GLES 2.0 option in AVD setting.Solves my problem.

[image]

Comment: but now the emulator runs slower

Comment: @CodeToLife what is your machine configuration? if you are using windows platform install HAXM and if you are using ubuntu install KVM.

Comment: yes , installed. and the machine is uptodate seems, with 1150 socket  MB, gt630, but with hardware option in that red framed dropdown it runs much faster than with usb device.

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT**

It seems like the issue is solved in Android Studio 2.2.3. If for some reason you still see this problem, the solution below works.

**Original answer**

I found a reasonable solution for now.
The problem is mainly in the launcher, not the emulator itself.
So installing a different launcher can fix the issue.
I installed the GO launcher from here: http://www.appsapk.com/go-launcher-ex/

Just drag and drop the apk on the emulator and install it, then tell the OS to use it as default.

I am not sure if this specific apk is a legal copy of the apk, but anyway it solves the issue for me and there are many launchers out there

good luck.

Comment: I can agree, surprisingly it started to work like a charm!

Comment: I would  suggest one without internet permission

Comment: I can't see that Android studio 2.3.3 solved the issue? I have a Mac mini 2012 With Intel HD Graphics 4000 (running Win10 (and OSX)) and then I have a component built PC Intel motherboard with Intel HD Graphics 3000, same thing. I still have this issue with everything but the stock Nexus play store units. The TV and Wear units works with the SW graphics acceleration fix below. The other Phone and Tablet units are unusable slow including both x86 and ARM. Looks like the units need update (because in previous versions of AS they worked so fine). Intel has no update Win10 driver, not an issue.

Comment: Interesting is that the stock Nexus play store units looks to learn, do not go into this indefinite loop of errors?? So they are usable after clicking away the errors. Also interesting is that I blank installed AS 2.3.3 on my Intel board PC and there are fuzz, but I upgraded my Mac Mini from AS 2.2.3 and the the emulator units from 2.2.3 works fine?? However I get the same "Your GPU driver information"-message asking to look for new Graphics board Win10 drivers. MS latest is from 2015 and and Intel's is elder. In short no new drivers, and that is no path, MS will not do anything about it?

Comment: Also interesting is that the old HAXM-issue where Win Hyper-V (must be disabled) is getting back, due to Win10 upgrades that puts it back. The AS people have been very keen on getting a smooth switch off, but it don't look to work from the AS, Hyper-V is still on. But it is off doing it manually but in Win10 culture the control panel, programs and functions Windows functions setting is easiest way of switching it off. True old fuzz and hazzel coming back on you. So a reminder always helps.

Comment: 5/2018 and this problem wasn't solved. C'mon Google!

Answer (score 10):

clearing launcher app data may help

```
adb shell pm clear com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher
```

Comment: This only works partially for me. The launcher no longer crashes by itself, but it does crash every time the app is launched. Uninstalling and reinstalling the app does not help.

Comment: @PointedEars - that is expected, since you haven't fixed the underlying problem, which is that your app crashes the emulator.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to fix this by turning off "App suggestions" in the Pixel Launcher Settings. You can open the settings panel with this command:

```
adb shell am start com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.SettingsActivity
```

Comment: this command only works untill I updatd system image. Comming here again as it resolved the problem last time :). Also the only you should add to the answer above: " On the emulator in opened settings window of that launcher  disable all check boxes".

Answer (score 0):

Some good suggestions above but I found out that it was crashing for me because the HAXM RAM specified was more than the AVD RAM.

I started getting the pixel launcher crash after I updated to the latest emulator version (26.1.2) and to the latest HAXM version (6.0.6). By default the HAXM RAM was set to 2GB and the RAM allocated to my virtual device was 1536MB. After I updated the HAXM RAM to 1GB I stopped getting the pixel launcher crashes.

To update the HAXM RAM you will need to run the HAXM installer again. Refer to this link [HAXM configuration in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366511/haxm-configuration-in-android-studio)

Comment: I could not find the HAXM installer in my GNU+Linux Android SDK.

But this might be a general “out of resources” issue: It started occurring for me when I only allocated one of my CPU cores to the emulator under “Show Advanced Settings” (since I wanted one idle for distributed computing), but left “Multi-Core CPU” checked. Switching the setting back to the default 2 cores made the problem disappear. Emulating a Pixel phone with Android Oreo, SDK 27 with Google API).

Comment: The RAM values in answer seem backwards.  Should be HAXM RAM >= virtual device RAM, right?  Otherwise, you won't be running in high-speed mode.  [So if you really do mean the numbers you say here, then you were having a problem running virtualized mode, and your "fix" worked by forcing emulator to run in the slower, but more reliable, emulated mode. Lessening your HAXM memory below AVD RAM was an indirect way to force that.]

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me to simply clean the project

Answer (score 0):

After one day of troubleshooting this issue, I just deleted the emulator and created another one with a **different name**. Now it working but still very slow. maybe I have to upgrade my laptop.

Comment: An alternative to deleting an emulator is to launch emulator manager and use it to "Start" the desired emulator. On "Start" screen, check "wipe user data".  That gets you back to a clean state.