# I can't change intel HAXM settings

Tags: android-studio, intel, hyper-v, haxm

After following the instructions in [Intel - installing the Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture)

I tried installing the intelhaxm-android.exe

However, after installing the change and repair is greyed out, i want to be able to adjust the RAM size but now unable to.

[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. I had to uninstall and reinstall HAXM using the command line as shown in the following answer. The second command installs HAXM allowing you to specify the amount of memory:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35771528/1330650