# Cannot swipe notifications menu down on Android L running on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop

On a Mac, cannot swipe notifications screen down.
The emulator screen is scaled down, but original size don't work either.

Is this a know issue? Can anyone reproduce that?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IhoI.jpg) is my AVD details.
[Here](http://youtu.be/YgJx8SL6XWs) is a video of me trying to get notifications menu.

[UPDATE 1]: [Opened an issue on android-preview tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=423)
[UPDATE 2]: Issue was marked as duplicate of [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=347).

Comment: Same problem on Windows too.

Comment: Any news about it? I also still have a very slow emulator, no matter which configuration I use (and I've also tried installing the intel driver)...

Comment: @androiddeveloper, I suggest you start the emulator on command line. It will print information if the intel acceleration cannot start.

Comment: @motobói The intel driver can't even be installed, as it says it's not supported. weird thing is that I think my PC should be able to support it, and I'm not the only one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/running-the-new-intel-emulator-for-android

Comment: I'm getting this on Windows 7 too.

Comment: @androiddeveloper did you got the "VT not enabled" message? If this is the case, you must enable VT on Bios settings

Comment: @motobói well it's enabled, and still it doesn't work (says it's not supported): http://i.stack.imgur.com/LA6b0.jpg . even if it's not supported, my PC should be able to run it smoothly, just like it can emulate consoles, video games, and desktop OSs ...