# Android studio emulator shows only "android"

Tags: android, android-emulator

I tried launching Emulator in android studio, but the emulator never started. It just shows "android" on the screen of the emulator window. I'm using windows OS. I also tried USB debugging but even the running device did not show. I have installed necessary drivers required for USB debugging, I'm using Xperia E dual phone.
I've tried creating AVD of 768 MB but did not help.
I've also installed all the necessary packages like HAXM etc etc..
Thank you !!!

Comment: Try to check log is there any error or warning shown regarding emulator.

Comment: @Haresh Chhelana where do check the logs??

Comment: Android log menu at bottom panel.

Comment: @Haresh Chhelana Yes I'm getting this error messages =>                                                      emulator: device fd:788
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.
creating window 40 81 335 557

Answer (score 0):

Download your Xperia E dual Phone Driver and install and ruun your apk with you phone . Downloa From [Xperia driver](http://androidxda.com/download-sony-xperia-usb-driver)

may be you have installed new emulator. so try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/running-the-new-intel-emulator-for-android)  for HAXM

Comment: no they are not providing the driver or driver update on the site. On the site it gives link to PC companion.

Comment: you says that you have installed your phone driver in PC. Now tell me that have you switch on Developer option in your phone.?

Comment: First switch on Developer option and connect with pc. after you can see your device connected with avd.

Comment: Yes, I've enabled the USB debugging mode......check my question, I've already mentioned that...

Comment: i have update my answer check it may be helpful to you.