# AVD not getting Created in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-virtual-device

I used windows 10. and i have a VISION AMD Processor when i trying to start an AVD at that time below error is occurred what is the solution for that types of error.i already install all tools and extra services from SDK and i have all SDK version.Please help me out for Solution.

ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable. CPU acceleration status: Android Emulator requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX support.  Your CPU: 'AuthenticAMD'

Answer (score 1):

You can cross check with this post  [Running the new Intel emulator for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761696/running-the-new-intel-emulator-for-android)