# Eclipse ADB not launching

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adb

I'm trying to run an application through ADB using Eclipse. However the application doesn't launch on my phone. Here's the log from Android console:

```
[2014-02-27 22:31:52 - HelloWorld-android] ------------------------------
[2014-02-27 22:31:52 - HelloWorld-android] Android Launch!
[2014-02-27 22:31:52 - HelloWorld-android] adb is running normally.
[2014-02-27 22:31:52 - HelloWorld-android] Performing com.teddygaming.helloworld.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-02-27 22:31:52 - HelloWorld-android] Uploading HelloWorld-android.apk onto device '4790050082a3106c'
[2014-02-27 22:31:53 - HelloWorld-android] Installing HelloWorld-android.apk...
[2014-02-27 22:32:03 - HelloWorld-android] Success!
[2014-02-27 22:32:03 - HelloWorld-android] Starting activity com.teddygaming.flappymuhittin.MainActivity on device 4790050082a3106c
```

There doesn't seem to be any error here, but it just doesn't launch.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, with adt-bundle installed, using OpenJDK 7. USB Debugging is enabled on my phone. I have edited /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules and added my vendor id. I've tried restarting adb server but that didn't work either. Please help me with this, I can't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: I was being a bit lazy, but I found these that could work:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845365/eclipse-becomes-stuck-on-starting-activity-when-sending-application-to-device

Comment: Thanks but they didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

May be it's crashing. Check the logcat log.
Also print a line in the first line of onCreate() of com.teddygaming.flappymuhittin.MainActivity.

Comment: I've added `System.out.println("Activity created");` to my onCreate() function but it's not printed. Logcat is empty.

Comment: use log.d(), system.out.println is used for printing in consoles, not in logcat log.

Comment: I used `Log.d("Main Activity", "Activity started");` but I still don't get any output in logcat

Comment: grab the logcat log with adb and post here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you launch in emulators? Also, I think you've already done this, but make sure Security->Unknown Sources is checked on your phone.

Comment: Yes, running in an emulator works, as well as transferring the apk to the device manually and then running it. Unknown sources is also checked.

Comment: Kinda last ditch efforts since the install is successful:
-Make sure the debugger is closed
-Restart your phone
-Update Eclipse and ADT
If those don't work post your phone's rules, maybe it's incomplete.