# Need to start new emulator every time while debugging Android app

Tags: android, android-emulator

Unlike iPhone/iPad Emulator, Android Emulator doesn't remain active in AVD.

Once (for first time only) I run the app on emulator, it works, quiet slow though.

I go back in the code, do some changes and try to test new code on emulator, but for second time, the existing emulator doesn't show up in the AVD Manager list. Yes, after last debug, I came back to home screen, retried to Run, AVD Manager pop up and shows me only my android phone connected but not the emulator.

I tried this([Eclipse not running Android app on emulator a second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290879/eclipse-not-running-android-app-on-emulator-a-second-time)) answer already but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: you shouldn't need to find it again in the AVD Manager list, you should just be able to hit the run button and it will push to the emulator that is already started.

Comment: Make sure you only have one copy of the Android SDK/NDK on your PC. I had several (don't ask), and ran into something similar.

Comment: @FoamyGuy .. Yes, I should be able to, but when I retry to run, eclipse console shows me error: "No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD."

Comment: try using `adb kill-server` and then `adb devices` to re-start your adb connection. Sometimes it gets disconnected after a while.

Comment: @FoamyGuy ... Yuhooooo.. . restarting the adb connection was the trick.. Thank you.. My Console isn't showing me any update now, but that's not a great deal. I'll try to figure that out.

Comment: would suggest to use `adb start-server` to start your adb again.