# Android emulator generates a very annoying error

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

It happens from time to time and really annoying. The system and application which I'm trying to test are still working, but the message prevents me from testing and it is annoying because happens from time to time.
The message says: `The process android.process.acore has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.`

Emulator's target name: "Google APIs (Google inc.)"
OS version: 15 (4.0.3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with Android 4.0 I think that you run the AVD with the default settings. The problem in this case is that there is not enough memory for AVD that run Android 4.0. Try to increase the device memory. You can see how to do this on the snapshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

A few possibilities:

1) After you see the error, wait a few seconds then right click the project and run as Android application again (on the same, running emulator)

2) Try deleting and then creating a new AVD. This one may have been corrupted.

3) Uninstall and then reinstall the whole SDK

If none of these work, try running through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317167/helloandroid-emulator-problem/7167568#7167568)

Comment: +1 Deleting and re-creating the AVD worked for me.  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to follow some steps:

1. Open your android virtual device and edit device which is giving probem.
2. After click on edit, edit following settings:

   1. Change your RAM memory to 1024
   2. Virtual heap 32
   3. Internal storage 200 mb
   4. External storage 64 mb
3. Your problem is now solved. Close the opened emulator and restart it again.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue after i had upgraded my system to i7 and 64 bit windows 7..

I had tried shutting down and recreating emulators without any success.

later I just increased the `heap size from 16 to 32` and it started working like anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the sampe problem, this is the solution :

The solution:
Settings –> Applications –> Manage Applications –> All (button on the top that lets you see all applications) –> scroll down to “Contacts Storage” –> Click on “Clear Data”.

IT WORKED EVEN IN THE EMULATOR, you should do this to every emulator type you want to use, 
this is where I found the solutions : 
http://www.shaneycrawford.com/2011/12/how-to-fix-the-android-process-acore-problem-on-an-android-device/

Answer (score 0):

You can check "Wipe user data" option in AVDM "Launch Options" dialog before starting your damaged virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have `reduced the Ram Memory from 1024 to 512` and the `Heap size from 64 to 32` and these actions stopped the error...

Answer (score 0):

One of the other reasons why this error comes is: 
Entry of that activity is not present in the AndroidManifest.xml.

After the entry is done, error disappears.