# Android emulator just won't start

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

i really need some help with this..i have done a lot of search and googling but none of the solutions worked out for me..
until 2-3 months ago i could get the emulator running at a decent time..but lately the emulator won't start..it will stay forever in the "android" screen..
i ve uninstalled and reinstalled sdk 2-3 times
after uninstall i also had system checked and restarted for potential errors..but no result
i ve installed all the necessary files, images etc..
i ve tried cmd launching no difference..disabling boot aniumation, still nothing..
i even left the emulator all night long to load but still no success..
the only solution left that i can think of is fresh install of the windows from the scratch.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you run

> adb -e logcat

Command, try to see if there's anything meaningful displayed there? 
That command accesses the log for the currently running emulator.

It might shed more light on the boot loop.

Comment: can you please tell me full path to run this? yesterday before uninstall the logcat (over esclipse) was literally "on fire" it kept displaying messages.. but there is no "weird logging" today.. :S

Comment: try Android SDKs\platform-tools\adb.exe from the comamnd prompt :)

Comment: shall i load log to rapidshare or sth..?? lots of lines.. :S

Comment: seems like you're getting many ANR's (Application-Not-Responding) during startup, did you try to delete the AVD image and recreate a new one? Maybe try different versions of Android images e.g 2.2, 2.3, 3.x ,4.x

Comment: Try also looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317167/helloandroid-emulator-problem/7167568#7167568 might be of help

Comment: i have deleted and remade avds many many times.. but it didn't help at all.. :S

Comment: the other stack overflow link didn't improve the situation afterall..i did install it in root directory c:/ i editted process so that to use both processors..but still nothing..