# How to target Android 4.1 Jelly Bean in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am new to Android development, I just got Eclipse for the first time a few days ago. 
I've made a simple app in Eclipse which I've got running through the emulator, but it's pointed at Android 4.3.

In Eclipse I've gone to Window -> Android Virtual Device Manager -> Edit, but the only "Target" in the list is Android 4.3 - API Level 18. I am using Nexus 4 as the device to emulate.

I've Googled (and Stackoverflow'd!) around for this to no avail. I haven't seen any articles which clearly outline what needs to be done to get Android 4.1 to appear in that list, and if there are any steps afterwards that I need to follow.

Do I need to download anything; is it just a configuration thing?

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use android ADT-Bundle.it support all API level. http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the SDK packages for the versions you want to target. Open the Android SDK Manager from Window->Android SDK Manager, then check the box for the latest Android 4.1 (API level 16).

Comment: Hi, thanks everyone for all of your help. I have installed the SDK and changed the Nexus 4 target to 4.1.2 now. I have run the emulator; it's been loading for nearly 5 min now (on the "ANDROID" screen). Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: @b85411 Please upvote helpful answers and accept one if it was what helped you figure out your issue.

Comment: I've accepted yours. Don't have enough points to up vote yet... I'm still not sure I've done it correctly though seeing the emulator is taking so long to load. I stopped and re-started, it's been going nearly 20 minutes now. Surely that isn't normal?

Comment: @b85411 The Android emulator really can take quite a while to start up, especially on Windows, but this sounds unusual. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317167/helloandroid-emulator-problem/7167568#7167568

Comment: For some reason, adding a new emulator fixed it. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed Android 4.3 image only.

Try to install other SDKs using android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ur direcotry where you have placed your android sdk and run **sdk manager**

[image]

You will get whole list of supported API's

Just go ahead and download the required one
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install [SDK's](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and [Plugin's](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) if you haven't installed.. Go through the links I mentioned, you will have an actual idea.

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If want to configure in eclipse then you've to update the latest version in your SDK manager.You can also use android ADT-Bundle.it support all API level.You can download from the [developer site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).