# Can't run android app from Eclipse with Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

**Can't run Android Apps from Eclipse with Emulator (Update: It has been solved)** 
I was trying to run this Doodlz app with Emulator and every time I run it just the Emulator comes up and nothing happens.
I Downloaded Eclipse then Installed SDK and API 10.
here is a screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kclzb.png
and the console:
[2014-09-04 00:02:40 - Address Book] ------------------------------
[2014-09-04 00:02:40 - Address Book] Android Launch!
[2014-09-04 00:02:40 - Address Book] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-04 00:02:40 - Address Book] Performing com.deitel.addressbook.AddressBook activity launch
[2014-09-04 00:02:40 - Address Book] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Test'
[2014-09-04 00:02:40 - Address Book] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Test'
[2014-09-04 00:02:41 - Address Book] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-09-04 00:02:41 - Address Book] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-09-04 00:08:08 - Address Book] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.deitel.addressbook.AddressBook activity launch'!

**Update**
Solved the problem with this answer: 
[HelloAndroid emulator problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317167/helloandroid-emulator-problem/)

Comment: Have you tried to launch emulator first, and then run your app?

Comment: We might need some more details for this to be debuggable...

Comment: @DKMudrechenko you mean i should lucnh it from SDK manager?

Comment: @Ondkloss  what details you need to know? have you seen the screen shot?

Comment: @Noise How long have you waited? On my PC the emulator takes about 10-15 minutes to load.

Comment: @Gumbo I tried waiting now. Got this Error: [2014-09-04 00:05:44 - Address Book] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.deitel.addressbook.AddressBook activity launch'!

Comment: @Ondkloss, yes - launch it from SDK manager and wait until it is loaded, and ten run your app from eclipse using emulator as a target device

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should looking at **genymotion**, the best android emulator i was used.
With the android emulator of android SDK, you should run it before run or debug the application, cause SDK emulator is very slow to start or do  everything.